# Microsoft File Share Storage Sync

Tags: azure-storage, azure-file-share

Is there a way to sync files that are saved either **locally** or in **GitLab** to the **Microsoft File Shares** storage? So I want it to be **unidirectional local** -> **File Shares** storage.

I did not find anything yet. I know there is a way to do it when using a **Blob** storage, via the `azcopy sync` command.

A way to do it is to delete all files first and then use the `az storage file upload-batch` command but this is way too cumbersome and ugly.

I even checked the `rclone` cli but this is also not possible for the **Microsoft File Shares** storage.

Am I missing something? This is ridiculous...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer:

Syntax

```
azcopy sync '<local-directory-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<file-share-name><SAS-token>' --recursive --delete-destination 'true'
```

Example from [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files#synchronize-files):

```
azcopy sync 'C:\myDirectory' 'https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileShare?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-07-04T05:30:08Z&st=2019-07-03T21:30:08Z&spr=https&sig=CAfhgnc9gdGktvB=ska7bAiqIddM845yiyFwdMH481QA8%3D' --recursive --delete-destination 'true'
```